# php form not sending submission data. sending email and processing form still however

Tags: php, forms, contact-form, submission

I Have two forms on my site. One works fine and the other sends email with email_from: etc but doesn't capture any of the form data.

Wondering what it may be. I can post the form that is working along with it's html too if that would help debug. Very much a novice and built form using stack overflow/other sites.

> Coffee

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Quantity</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                          <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity : " required>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name : " required>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email address</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                          <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address : " required>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Shipping Address</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                          <textarea class="form-control" name="shipping_address" rows="8" placeholder="Shipping Address : " required></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Payment Method</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                          <select class="form-control" required>
                            <option value="Paypal">Paypal</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Notes</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                          <textarea class="form-control" name="notes" rows="8" placeholder="Notes : "></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-10">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-black">Order Now</button></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST ['submit'])) 

{

 $coffee = ($_POST['coffee']));
 $quantity = ($_POST['quantity']));
 $name = ($_POST['name']));
 $email = ($_POST['email']));
 $shipping_address = ($_POST['shipping_address']));
 $notes = ($_POST['notes'])); 
 }

$email_from ='paradigmcoffee@gmail.com';
$email_subject="New Order Submission";
$email_body ="You have received a new message from user $name.\n".
"Email_address:$email\n".
"Coffee: $coffee\n".
"Quantity: $quantity\n".
"Shipping_Address: $shipping_address\n".
"Notes: $notes\n".

$to ="paradigmcoffee@gmail.com";
$headers = "From: $email \r\n";

mail($to,$email_from,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
header("Location: http://www.paradigmcoffee.co/order_thanks.html");
?>
```

Comment: did you try echo $email_body in your php, does it gets all the fields?

Comment: Why do you have 2 closing parenthesis at the end of every post variable you read ? I think this should give you at least a warning, if not an error.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have supplied, likely the reason you can not get data is because you are not sending anything called `submit`. Try naming your button:

```
<!-- name="submit" added -->
<button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-black">Order Now</button>
```

You can do this or make a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="1" />
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what specifically but after removing parenthesis on the variables and renaming the "submit" button (I have another form in the same directory also named "submit") + adding the hidden input field it worked fine. php seemed to have trouble finding/calling the html action